Multi-layer Angular Content Projection?
Preface: I am trying to accomplish something I'm not sure is possible in angular.
I have a component that uses multi-slot projection, as so:
parent.html:
<my-component>
  <item slot="header"></item>
  <item slot="main"></item>
</my-component>

my-component.html:
<header class="header">
  <ng-content select="[slot=header]"></ng-content>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <ng-content select="[slot=main]"></ng-content>
</main>

That works.
Now, is there a way to allow for a second layer of content projection, where I pass another slot within the first.
Using the same example, but adding in an additional component:
parent.html:
<my-component>
  <item slot="header">
    <nav slot="nav">...</nav> <!-- THIS -->
    ...
  </item>
  <item slot="main"></item>
</my-component>

my-component.html:
<my-header-component>
  <ng-content select="[slot=header]"></ng-content>
</my-header-component>
<main class="main">
  <ng-content select="[slot=main]"></ng-content>
</main>

my-header-component.html:
<header class="header">
  <ng-content select="[slot=nav]"></ng-content> <!-- and THIS -->
  <div class="additional-content">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</header>

Is something like that possible? or do I need to rethink what I'm doing. :P

yes i think it's possible and it works, i dont really know your use case but maybe NgTemplateOutlet can help too
